# What format for Unicode titles submitted to Wikipedia api via Swift?

Tags: swift, unicode, wikipedia

This is what I would *like* to submit to Wikipedia from Swift via curl, but it naturally doesn't work (I get back a munge of 'titles'):

```
"https://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=jsonfm&maxlag=2&rvslots=main&titles=Deca_Loših_Muzičara"
```

What format does Wikipedia expect (can you give the solution?), and how do I get Swift to convert to it?  Plain ASCII chars work fine. Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect to get?

Comment: I expect the JSON of the music group's page. I've tried various formats, e.g. ```titles=Deca_Lo\\u0161ih_Muzi\\u010dara```.  Again, plain ASCII works fine, I get back pages for other groups.  Just the special chars give me trouble.  Thanks.

Comment: Partial solution:  I need to learn how to convert "titles=Deca_Lo\\u0161ih_Muzi\\u010dara" to "titles=Deca_Lo%C5%A1ih_Muzi%C4%8Dara" (the latter works as input to Wikipedia).

Answer (score -1):

Solved:

`

```
let transform = "Any-Hex/Java"
let theCopy = argString.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableString
CFStringTransform( theCopy, nil, transform as NSString, true)
let encodedURLString = theCopy.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
let urlPath: String = encodedURLString!
let url: NSURL = NSURL( string: urlPath)!
```

`

A simpler method would be better.